# How to convert an array into an object of specific format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Although it is a common problem but I couldn't find any lead to get the desired result. So here is the problem. I have the following array:

```
[
    [ 'a' ]
    [ 'a', 'b' ]
    [ 'a', 'c' ]
    [ 'a', 'c', 'd' ]
    [ 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
]
```

And what I want as an end result is an object like this:

```
{
  a: {
    b: {},
    c: { d: { e: {} } }
  }
}
```

I don't understand which approach would be better to get this result and how to achieve it.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: look away to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Yes, basically you want to iterate through every element in the array and do a custom aggregation, which reduce is perfect for. Alternatively you can use a for loop to iterate over the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a double reduce, one for the outer array and one for the keys and the nesting objects.

```js
var data = [['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']],
    result = data.reduce((r, keys) => {
        keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, r);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that if the data source is untrusted, this is susceptible to [prototype pollution](https://codeburst.io/what-is-prototype-pollution-49482fc4b638). Consider `['__proto__', 'toString', 123]` as input. This problem exists with any simple approach unless special countermeasures are taken (skip `__proto__` and `constructor`) or a library is used that takes them for you.

Comment: Wow this solution is so elegant and beautiful. Time to say goodbye to for loops for good. I am gonna learn more about functional programming now.

Comment: I was working on an answer but wasn't as good. I pasted Nina's answer into a sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mcnulty-8lcbv?file=/src/index.js